# getting name of android shortcut

Tags: android, shortcut

I am trying to create an app which will create multiple shortcut of the same app with user input as the shortcut name. but every shortcut will do different specified things.For this I need to know the shortcut name.any possible way to fo that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Shortcut for android application To home screen On button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343414/add-shortcut-for-android-application-to-home-screen-on-button-click)

Comment: Hi @Ratul ! Did you find a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need the INSTALL_SHORTCUT permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

You can use the code below and make changes

```
EditText UserInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userinput_text);
final String UserString = UserInput.getText().toString();
//Gets user input^

public void createIcon(){
    Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    //So the shortcut doesn't get created multiple times
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

    //UserString is the text from the user input to set the shortcut name
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(UserString));

    //set the icon picture
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon);

    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new 

    //Set the Activity that will be opened
    Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnterActivity.class));

    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
}
```

That will add a shortcut to the launcher and open a custom activity from your app. I'm not sure what you're really trying to do as it's unclear of what you're asking for.